# Extracting value from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to get specific value from an array that is filled with news items and its parameters.

My array has 25 items, from 6 different categories, I need to get only category name but not 25 times. If I'm not entirely clear, just say so

This is `print_r($this->primary)`:

```
Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
         [title]=> Title 1
         [categoryname]=> Cat1
         [categoryid]=> 2
        )
   [1] => stdClass Object
        (
         [title]=> Title 2
         [categoryname]=> Cat1
         [categoryid]=> 2
        )


   [2] => stdClass Object
        (
         [title]=> Title 3
         [categoryname]=> Cat2
         [categoryid]=> 3
        )
   [3] => stdClass Object
        (
         [title]=> Title 4
         [categoryname]=> Cat2
         [categoryid]=> 3
        )
)
```

My loop is:

```
for each ($getids->categories as $key=>$mycategory)
{
    echo ' <h2> CAT NAME SHOULD GO HERE</h2> ';
    for each ($this->primary as $key=>$item){
        if ($mycategory == $item->categoryid){
            echo $item->title;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I need the category name ***before*** starting the `for each`. The stupid thing is that `$getids->categories` is not giving me anything else but category ID. I can't fetch it with `$this->primary[0]` because the items are not grouped per category, but are just rolled in to the array as you can see above ,

any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**: This is `print_r($getids->categories)`:

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => 11
     [1] => 14
     [2] => 12
     [3] => 13
     [4] => 15
     [5] => 21
     [6] => 20
     [7] => 29
 )
```

Comment: What is `$getids->categories` in your foreach loop? Can you update your question with the print_r of `$getids->categories`?

Comment: @humayun , updated , it is just giving me the category id's

Comment: Ok but what's expected in `$getids->categories`? Categoryname as well?

Comment: no , that is menu item giving me what categories to fetch items from , and is not giving me anything else but their id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you,

```
foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item)
{
    $headingPrinted = false;
    foreach($getids->categories as $key=>$catID) {
        if($catID == $item->categoryid){
            if (!$headingPrinted) {
                echo '<h2>'.$item->categoryname.'</h2>';
                $headingPrinted = true;
            }
            echo $item->title;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what can I say ,   simpler than arranging the array

Answer (score 1):

With your current setup, you have no option except to call categoryName 25 times. If you want to avoid doing this, I would consider refactoring your code so that $this->primary is not filled with everything. Assuming you are grabbing these values from a model, you could change your model function to restrict by category name.

```
foreach($categoryNames as $categoryName) {
    $this->primaryArray[$categoryName] = Foo.getByCategoryName($categoryName);
}

foreach($this->primaryArray as $categoryName => $primary) {
    echo '<h2>' . $categoryName . '</h2>';
    foreach($primary as $key=>$item){
        echo $item->title;
    }
}
```

EDIT

To sort by categories (though you will still call 25 times):

```
$primaryArray = array();

// sort array by category
foreach($this->primary as $value) {
    $primaryArray[$value->categoryName] = $value;
}

foreach($primaryArray as $categoryName => $primary) {
    echo '<h2>' . $categoryName . '</h2>';
    foreach($primary as $key=>$item){
        echo $item->title;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant edit any core files , must use what I have and that is what I posted above ,

Comment: I dont mind , calling it 25 times , but I need it displayed only once per items group , so if I have 6 cats , there should be only 6 cat titles , not 25

Comment: In that case... you could arrange them manually by yourself. But, of course, that defeats the purpose, since you're still calling it 25 times XD

Comment: and how would I do that? that is the purpose of the question

Comment: Edited to add manual arrangement. Not the most efficient answer, but it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to preserve the order of categories as returned by $getids->categories, you could try something like this:

```
//Group items by category.
$itemsByCategory = array()
foreach($this->primary as $item) {
    if ( !isset($itemsByCategory[$item->categoryid] ) {
        $itemsByCategory[$item->categoryid] = array();
    }
    $itemsByCategory[$item->categoryid][] = $item;
}

//Print items in each category.
foreach($getids->categories as $mycategory):
    if ( isset($itemsByCategory[$mycategory]) ) {
        $categoryName = $itemsByCategory[$mycategory][0]->categoryname;
        echo '<h2>', $categoryName ,'</h2>';
        foreach($$temsByCategory[$mycategory] as $key=>$item){
           echo $item->title;
        }
    }

endforeach;
```

Comment: Yep, missed it by *that much* :)